# cabalのサブコマンドのnew-*とv2-*は同じものを指していますか

Tags: haskell

現在のcabalが提供するサブコマンドに new-* と v2-* というプレフィックスがついたものがあります。手元で試した限りでは同じ動作をするように見えますが、これらは同じものを指していますか？
またこれらが正式なサブコマンドになる（プレフィックスが外れる）予定はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cabalのドキュメントの該当するセクション](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build-overview.html)の冒頭に書いてありました。

> 手元で試した限りでは同じ動作をするように見えますが、これらは同じものを指していますか？

下記の一節にありました。スクリプトやドキュメントではこちらを使った方がいいのかも知れません。

> （前略）... there are also v2- prefixed versions that will reference the same functionality until such a point as it is completely removed from Cabal.

---

> またこれらが正式なサブコマンドになる（プレフィックスが外れる）予定はありますか？

下記のとおり、 "those names are only temporary" とのことです。

> The Nix-style local build system is commonly called “new-build” for short after the cabal new-* family of commands that control it. However, those names are only temporary until Nix-style local builds become the default.

また、伝聞で恐縮ですが、[「cabal HEADでnew-*コマンドがデフォルトに置き換えられた」というtweet](https://twitter.com/ma0e/status/1082581818073739264)からも窺えます。  
（正確にどのコミットからかはすぐにはわかりませんでしたが...）